# Trouble sharing an mp3 audio stored in the raw folder via whatsApp

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I'm having trouble sharing an mp3 audio stored in the raw folder via whatsApp, I know it has dozens of posts on it, but many have no answer ... and those who had answers did not help me much.

So I'll post my code here, if, please, anyone can help me ...

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("audio/*");
            shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + rawId +".mp3"));
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(shareIntent);
```

**Note** - if I do not put the .mp3 extension on str of uri whatsApp reports Unsupported file. And if I put it informs Failed to share.

I'm trying to make this share without having to write the file in the external area (SDCard). I would like to send direct from the raw folder, without having to copy anywhere, but it is not working, someone knows how and if I can do it?

Comment: Same problem here. Gmail is also problematic, if I don't put ".mp3" it doesn't send as an audio file but if i do, it cannot locate file. Could you find a solution?

Comment: @Emre Sülün Yeah, just putting .mp3 works. What is bother me it's that way any sounds that you send is now listed in the music library. And this for sure bother the user.